# Python 3.3 - Formatting Information in a Table

Tags: python, python-3.3

Currently I am trying to display information from a table into the console line. I have tried formatting the data but it does not seem to want to change.

The code for the formatting is:

```
  print("{:>21}".format("Student Table")) #Title
  print("{:>5} {:>8} {:>8}".format(col_names[0], col_names[1], col_names[2])) #Column Names
  for row in rows:    
      print("{:^8} {:<50} {:<8}".format(*row)) #information formatting
```

The data then displays the following:

```
        Student Table
StudentID     Name     Year
   1     Dan                                                13      
   2     Laura                                              12      
   3     Joe                                                13      
   4     David                                              13      
   5     Jake                                               13
```

I am trying to reposition the Name information and have it aligned from the left so everything lines up with the column title.

I try changing the middle number on the information formatting but the information does not seem to change!

Please adivse me on how I can line up the information.

Comment: Does your data have spaces in it?

Comment: @Keith None of the data has spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Body format does not match header format. `StudentID` is 9 characters. So the first column length should be increased.

```
print("{:>9} {:<50} {:<8}".format(*col_names))
for row in rows:    
    print("{:^9} {:<50} {:>8}".format(*row))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **falsetru**'s answer, note that you can have a very dynamic formatting string; this way, left or right and width of the columns can be set depending on your values:

```
>>> '{0:{1}>{2}}'.format('some', '*', 10)
'******some'
>>> '{0:{1}{2}{3}}'.format('some', '*', '<', 10)
'some******'
>>> '{0:{1}{2}{3}}'.format('some', '*', '>', 10)
'******some'
```

Another good idea is to define the formatting string once, and use it everywhere possible.